# Ruby - cannot convert individual chars in string to ASCII

Tags: ruby

I am trying to run the following code on http://repl.it/languages/Ruby/, but I am encountering a `NoMethodError`:

```
a = "string"
a.each_char do |c|
    puts c.ord
end
```

The error details are as follows:

```
(eval):1: undefined method `ord' for "s":String (NoMethodError)
    from (eval):0:in `each_char'
    from (eval):0
```

Please could somebody explain to me why my code does not work?

Comment: That code does to what it is programmed to do (print the ASCII char code of each character). What output do you want to get from it?

Answer (score 1):

The [`each_char`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-each_char) method of [`String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html) yields each character as a separate `String`.

The Ruby version running on [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/Ruby/) is quite old (1.8.7). The `String` class in that version of Ruby doesn't define an `ord` method, so your code fails to run with a `NoMethodError`.

[`ord`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-ord) was added to `String` in Ruby 1.9, so your code will run on newer versions of Ruby.

On Ruby 1.8.7 (and repl.it), you could use one of the following alternatives instead:

```
a = "string"
a.each_char do |c|
    puts c[0]
end
```

```
a = "string"
a.each_byte do |c|
    puts c
end
```

However, please note that these examples won't behave identically to your original code if your string uses a multi-byte encoding. The `ord` method returns a Unicode code point. The Ruby 1.8.7 examples will give you individual bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The code as is will print the ascii code of each letter. Perhaps you're looking at the return value which would be the original string "string"?

Comment: hmm that's strange the above code doesn't work on /http://repl.it/languages/Ruby/ Maybe due to ruby versions?